# Instantiating ObservableList?

Tags: java, eclipse, observable, eclipse-databinding

I am trying to understand the concept of `ObservableList` and `Realms`. I have tried to create an instance of an `ObservableList` like this:

```
  public ObservableList createObservableList() {
    ObservableList myObsList = new ObservableList(new ArrayList<String>(),
        "test") {
    };

    return myObsList;
  }
```

But when I call this method I get:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:Realm cannot be null
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
```

I understand that this have something to do we the default realm is not set. But where do I find documentation on these concepts?

I have looked at this:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Observable

http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/list/ObservableList.html

...but it contains very limited information/examples.

I also have the Eclipse EMF book but cannot find any examples of how to use eg. `ObservableList`

Where do I find tutorials/documentation on rules/concepts behind Observable?

I have now tried the following:

```
  public static ObservableList createObservableList() {
    ObservableList myObsList = null;
    Realm.getDefault().exec(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        myObsList = new ObservableList(new ArrayList<String>(), "test") {
        };
      }
    });
    return myObsList;
  }
```

...but that does not work since `myObsList` must be final. Changing it to final makes it impossible to update it inside the run method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A Realm is not set be default. You can test, if a default realm is available:

```
if (Realm.getDefault() == null) {
```

and set a Realm (for the current thread) if necessary:

```
   Realm.setDefault(new Realm());
}
```

(JFace Databinding is a challenge...)

Comment: Seems the API has changed. `Realm.setDefault` is no longer visible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the static method

```java
SWTObservables.getRealm(display)
```

to get the Realm associated with the UI Thread of the given display. It would definitely be nice for the API page of Realm to provide some hint on this.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I sympathise, the Eclipse API is a weird one to work with sometimes.

I found this in the JFaces FAQ:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding_FAQ#What_is_a_Realm.2C_and_do_I_need_to_care.3F

It looks like you can run something in a realm using:

```
Realm.exec(Runnable runnable)
```

so try creating the observable list from inside the Runnable block.  Hope that helps.

See:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm.html

It would be nice if we had user friendly URL's Eclipse people !

Comment: You can hide the [URLs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm.html) behind short and readable names, works inside questions, answers and even on comments ;-)

Comment: Ok so there are no books currently released that covers ObservableList in depth like the EMF book and its coverage of ecore modelling?

Comment: Sure, but it'd still be nice to have Eclipse display user friendly URL's

Comment: The Eclipse API seems to be in a fair amount of flux, I don't think there's a book that can capture it.  A wiki of solutions and examples would be fantastic, I don't understand how they effectively "test" their API - surely documenting it in terms of use would be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your main class to implement Runnable inerface.
2. Move all logic to `run()` method
3. In static main method call `Realm.runWithDefault()`

   ```
   Main main = new Main();  
   Realm realm = SWTObservables.getRealm(Display.getDefault());  
   //for JFace data binding  
   Realm.runWithDefault(realm, main);
   ```